# Python, Deleting all files in a folder older than X days

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a python script to delete all files in a folder older than X days.  This is what I have so far:

```py
import os, time, sys
    
path = r"c:\users\%myusername%\downloads"
now = time.time()

for f in os.listdir(path):
  if os.stat(f).st_mtime < now - 7 * 86400:
    if os.path.isfile(f):
      os.remove(os.path.join(path, f))
```

When I run the script, I get:

`Error2 - system cannot find the file specified`,

and it gives the filename.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The question is not "How to delete files...", it is something like "why is my file missing after os.listdir?" or similar.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`os.listdir()` returns a list of bare filenames. These do not have a full path, so you need to combine it with the path of the containing directory. You are doing this when you go to delete the file, but not when you `stat` the file (or when you do `isfile()` either).

Easiest solution is just to do it once at the top of your loop:

```
f = os.path.join(path, f)
```

Now `f` is the full path to the file and you just use `f` everywhere (change your `remove()` call to just use `f` too).

Comment: Do I need to declare path when I declare f or what do you mean? I declared f at the beginning as you recommended but now it wants me to declare path for os.path. Or am I not understanding what you mean?

Comment: As I said, at the top of your loop (i.e., just after the `for` statement) put the statement I gave you. I can't say it any plainer than that.

Comment: Okay, I was declaring it in the wrong place. So, it should look like

for f in os.listdir(path):

f = os.path.join(path, f)

Is that about right?

Comment: Hello Great to see that people have already thought what I am thinking. One little addition. How to get in python the number of folders affected so that email can be sent at the end of the operation? thanks

Comment: What if i only want to delete file of certain extension?

Comment: Just add that to the `if` statement: `if os.path.isfile(f) and f.endswith(".ext"):`

Answer (score 24):

I think the new **pathlib** thingy together with the **arrow** module for dates make for neater code.

```
from pathlib import Path
import arrow

files_path = r"C:\scratch\removeThem"

critical_time = arrow.now().shift(hours=+5).shift(days=-7)

for item in Path(files_path).glob('*'):
    if item.is_file():
        print(str(item.absolute()))
        item_time = arrow.get(item.stat().st_mtime)
        if item_time < critical_time :
            # remove it
            pass
```

- **pathlib** makes it easy to list the directory contents, to access file characteristics such as as creation times and to get full paths.
- **arrow** makes calculations of times easier and neater.

Here's the output showing the full paths offered by **pathlib**. (No need to join.)

```
C:\scratch\removeThem\four.txt
C:\scratch\removeThem\one.txt
C:\scratch\removeThem\three.txt
C:\scratch\removeThem\two.txt
```

Comment: I like pathlib.  I'm not so sure about arrow yet.  I ended up using dateutil.relativedelta.

`criticalTime = (now + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(minutes=-60))` and `itemTime = datetime.fromtimestamp(item.stat().st_mtime)`

Comment: I will vouch for arrow.  Datetime math is simple and readable.

Answer (score 16):

You need to give it the path also or it will look in cwd..  which ironically enough you did on the `os.remove` but no where  else...

```
for f in os.listdir(path):
    if os.stat(os.path.join(path,f)).st_mtime < now - 7 * 86400:
```

Comment: Okay, I no longer get the error, but now it seems that, either it's going to take some time, or it's not actually deleting my files older than 7 days. Is my math wrong or do I have to set permissions somehow?

Comment: did you change the `os.isfile`  also? or that will evaluate to false... (or just do like kindall recommended and change f to be inclusive of the path...)

Comment: So I should have declared f at the beginning? Ouch. This is my very first Python script, I read a course but I learn better by doing.

Answer (score 13):

i did it in more sufficient way

```
import os, time

path = "/home/mansoor/Documents/clients/AirFinder/vendors"
now = time.time()

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    filestamp = os.stat(os.path.join(path, filename)).st_mtime
    seven_days_ago = now - 7 * 86400
    if filestamp < seven_days_ago:
        print(filename)
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to use `if os.stat(os.path.join(path, f)).st_mtime < now - 7 * 86400:` instead of `if os.stat(f).st_mtime < now - 7 * 86400:`

I find using `os.path.getmtime` more convenient :-

```
import os, time

path = r"c:\users\%myusername%\downloads"
now = time.time()

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    # if os.stat(os.path.join(path, filename)).st_mtime < now - 7 * 86400:
    if os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(path, filename)) < now - 7 * 86400:
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, filename)):
            print(filename)
            os.remove(os.path.join(path, filename))
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple python script to remove /logs/ files older than 10 days

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# run by crontab
# removes any files in /logs/ older than 10 days

import os, sys, time
from subprocess import call

def get_file_directory(file):
    return os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(file))

now = time.time()
cutoff = now - (10 * 86400)

files = os.listdir(os.path.join(get_file_directory(__file__), "logs"))
file_path = os.path.join(get_file_directory(__file__), "logs/")
for xfile in files:
    if os.path.isfile(str(file_path) + xfile):
        t = os.stat(str(file_path) + xfile)
        c = t.st_ctime

        # delete file if older than 10 days
        if c < cutoff:
            os.remove(str(file_path) + xfile)
```

With `__file__` you can replace by your path.

Answer (score 3):

This deletes files older than 60 days.

```
import os

directory = '/home/coffee/Documents'

os.system("find " + directory + " -mtime +60 -print")
os.system("find " + directory + " -mtime +60 -delete")
```

Answer (score 1):

With comprehensions, Can be:

```
import os
from time import time


p='.'
result=[os.remove(file) for file in (os.path.join(path, file) for path, _, files in os.walk(p) for file in files) if os.stat(file).st_mtime < time() - 7 * 86400]
print(result)
```

- remove files with match = os.remove(file)
- loop for all files into path = for file in
- generation with all files = (os.path.join(path, file) for path, _,
  files in os.walk(p) for file in files)
- p is a directory into filesystem
- verify mtime to match= if os.stat(file).st_mtime < time() - 7 * 86400

May be see: https://ideone.com/Bryj1l

Comment: Hi @britodfbr, firstly thank you for the solution provided. just a quick question, what does the variable `p` refer to? I mean the one in `os.walk(p)` ? Thanks!

Comment: @XavierSun `p='.'` means the current directory.  Though this soln seems odd to me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it on my Windows machines. It uses shutil to also remove subdirectories created in downloads.  I also have a similar one to keep the folders cleaned up on the hard drive of my son's computer, as he has special needs and tends to let things get out of control fast.

```
import os, time, shutil

paths = (("C:"+os.getenv('HOMEPATH')+"\Downloads"), (os.getenv('TEMP')))
oneday = (time.time())- 1 * 86400

try:
    for path in paths:
        for filename in os.listdir(path):
            if os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(path, filename)) < oneday:
                if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, filename)):
                    print(filename)
                    os.remove(os.path.join(path, filename))
                elif os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, filename)):
                    print(filename)
                    shutil.rmtree((os.path.join(path, filename)))
                    os.remove(os.path.join(path, filename))
except:
    pass
                
print("Maintenance Complete!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of the other answers also have the same code but i feel they have overcomplicated a very simple process

```
import os
import time

#folder to clear from
dir_path = 'path of directory to clean'
#No of days before which the files are to be deleted
limit_days = 10

treshold = time.time() - limit_days*86400
entries = os.listdir(dir_path)
for dir in entries:
    creation_time = os.stat(os.path.join(dir_path,dir)).st_ctime
    if creation_time < treshold:
        print(f"{dir} is created on {time.ctime(creation_time)} and will be deleted")
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be a tad late to the party but this is my approach using pathlib's timestamp to convert date object to a float and compare it to file.stat().st_mtime

```
from pathlib import Path
import datetime as dt
from time import ctime


remove_before = dt.datetime.now()-dt.timedelta(days=10) files older than 10 days

removeMe = Path.home() / 'downloads' # points to :\users\%myusername%\
for file in removeMe.iterdir(): 
    if remove_before.timestamp() > file.stat().st_mtime:
        print(ctime(file.stat().st_mtime)) 
        file.unlink() # to delete the file
```

Answer (score 0):

would like to add what i came up with to do this task.
the function is called in the login process.

```
    def remove_files():
        removed=0
        path = "desired path"
        # Check current working directory.
        dir_to_search = os.getcwd()
        print "Current working directory %s" % dir_to_search
        #compare current to desired directory
        if dir_to_search != "full desired path":
            # Now change the directory
            os.chdir( desired path )
            # Check current working directory.
            dir_to_search = os.getcwd()
            print "Directory changed successfully %s" % dir_to_search
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir_to_search):
           for file in filenames:
              curpath = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
              file_modified = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(curpath))
              if datetime.datetime.now() - file_modified > datetime.timedelta(hours=1):
                  os.remove(curpath)
                  removed+=1
        print(removed)
```

Answer (score 0):

just give the path directory and list down the files within it

```
destination_path = './level1/level2/path'
# delete archieve file older than 2 days
current_day = time.time()
for filename in os.listdir(destination_path):
   if os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(destination_path, filename)) < current_day - 1 * 86400:
      if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(destination_path, filename)):
         os.remove(os.path.join(destination_path, filename))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, cleanup old files and empty folders, and recursive:

```
import os
import time
from pathlib import Path

def cleanup_old_files(localRepo=LOCAL_PATH,age=60):

    critical_time = time.time() - age * 24 * 3600

    for item in Path(localRepo).expanduser().rglob('*'):
        if item.is_file():
            if os.stat(item).st_mtime < critical_time:
                os.remove(item)

    for item in Path(localRepo).expanduser().rglob('*'):    
        if item.is_dir():
            if len(os.listdir(item)) == 0:
                os.rmdir(item)
```