# How to get a list of files within a directory from a specific date period using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, filenames

So I am able to extract all the file names into a text file, but there are millions of results. How do I limit it to only look at files created in the last 24 hours/1 day ???

This is my code so far.

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as a:
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'\\somefolder'):
      for filename in files:
         f = os.path.join(filename)
         a.write(str(f) + os.linesep)
```

thank you for your help

Comment: have you tried [getting the last modified time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39501288/9209546), then [taking the difference between two times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25265500/9209546) and performing an `if` condition based on this value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, Deleting all files in a folder older than X days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485666/python-deleting-all-files-in-a-folder-older-than-x-days)