# How to delete files older than 14 days on Windows

Tags: python

We would like to delete files older than 14 days, the files are all named by date.log, supposed '20200515.log', how to delete those older files without deleting the running script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, Deleting all files in a folder older than X days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485666/python-deleting-all-files-in-a-folder-older-than-x-days)

Comment: Note the answer that had `Path(filesPath).glob('*'):` - doing `.glob('*.log')` will only match the log files.

Comment: Yes, I don't want it delete all files, I will try what you said about `glob` right now, thank you so much