# Find all files older than one minute in python

Tags: linux, python

I m trying to find files that are older than 1 min using python. Can someone help me with it?

I know we can use `subprocess` and use the linux find command but I want to write it in python.

```
with os.scandir(dirss) as listOfEntries:
        for entry in listOfEntries:
           data=os.path.join(dirss,entry)
           if os.stat(data).st_mtime < now + 1:
```

Comment: What is `now + 1`?

Comment: [python-deleting-all-files-in-a-folder-older-than-x-days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485666/python-deleting-all-files-in-a-folder-older-than-x-days) has code to find files oder then x days ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`st_mtime` (and the return value of `time.time()`) is in seconds. You might be looking for

```
import os
import time

with os.scandir(dirss) as listOfEntries:
    for entry in listOfEntries:
        age = time.time() - entry.stat().st_mtime
        if age > 60:
            print(os.path.join(dirss, entry.name), age)
```